# Same package name for iOS and Android apps in Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have added the iOS version of my App in firebase already, now I'm trying to add the Android version of the same App, but the problem is that both iOS and Android have the same package names. While adding Android, I'm getting the error `An unexpected error has occurred. [Reason: Requested entity already exists]`

Is it compulsory to keep bundle/package names different for both iOS and Android in firebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, both iOS and Android app can have same package name. In fact, I have an Android/iOS apps which are connected to Firebase. For security reasons, I have to hide package name and other confidential information. But as you can see, you just need to click **Add app** button and create 2 apps one for Android, one for iOS. Best regards.

Note: I added Android app first then added iOS App. If you still have a problem, there might be bug in Firebase side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really. One reason this could happen to you is when you tried to delete an app. So after deleting an app at firebase, it takes about 30 days to delete completely. Meaning the app is still yours for that period. So in order to use the package name again for another Android app, you need to delete it permanently yourself. You will see the app is pending deletion on your dashboard.